# Where HTML5 - Web SQL Database file store and Where all tables is Created

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I am new in Html5 Web SQL database I faced some Problem I downloaded a demo Project websqlApp When I run this Project it Store data Which i enter but i want to find out the database file which it is using .

I found some solution:-
C:\users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases

but this sqlite file is only show the database name but i want to the file which is show all table which is created into this database.

Comment: If i'm not wrong your using chrome, then you can see your data in chrome's developer tool inside resources>web sql tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in a SQLite database.

Web SQL locations by system for Google Chrome on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
```

You can use `Resources` tab in Chrome's developer tools (F12) to view the database.

OR

You can use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to open extensionless file that is an SQLite database.